# Problem connecting MySQL and Node.js docker containers using Docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm new with Docker and I'm trying to mount with docker compose two containers:
One for Node.js
Another for MySQL

The problem is that Docker notify my a TCPConnect error and I don't know howto fix this. I can connect to a mysql single container from my code initialized locally by "npm run dev".

- Entire Log info:

```
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:24:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.29-1debian10 started.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:24:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:24:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.29-1debian10 started.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:24:59+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:24:59.807583Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) initializing of server in progress as process 42
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:24:59.812287Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:00.170661Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
node_container   |
node_container   | > tests@1.0.0 dev
node_container   | > nodemon index.js
node_container   |
node_container   | [nodemon] 2.0.16
node_container   | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
node_container   | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
node_container   | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
node_container   | [nodemon] starting `node index.js`



node_container   |  user:johndoe
node_container   |  password: secret
node_container   |  database: Highschool_App
node_container   |  host: mysql_container



node_container   | Server running at port 3000!
node_container   | node:events:505
node_container   |       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
node_container   |       ^
node_container   |
node_container   | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED <container_ip>:3306 // modified 
node_container   |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1229:16)
node_container   | Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
node_container   |     at Connection._notifyError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:236:12)
node_container   |     at Connection._handleFatalError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:167:10)
node_container   |     at Connection._handleNetworkError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:180:10)
node_container   |     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
node_container   |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
node_container   |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
node_container   |     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
node_container   |   errno: -111,
node_container   |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
node_container   |   syscall: 'connect',
node_container   |   address: 'ip', // It was a container ip
node_container   |   port: 3306,
node_container   |   fatal: true
node_container   | }
node_container   |
node_container   | Node.js v18.3.0
node_container   | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:01.231824Z 6 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:25:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:25:04+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:04.802668Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) starting as process 91
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:04.813377Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:04.925189Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:05.083344Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:05.083370Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:05.084820Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:05.098414Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:05.098424Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:25:05+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
mysql_container  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_container  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_container  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_container  | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:25:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database Highschool_App
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:25:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user johndoe
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:25:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user johndoe access to schema Highschool_App
mysql_container  |
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:25:06+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:06.649562Z 13 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.29).
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:07.899110Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.29)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:25:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped
mysql_container  |
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16 15:25:08+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
mysql_container  |
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:08.844951Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) starting as process 1
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:08.850280Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:08.960931Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:09.080235Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:09.080263Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:09.081813Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:09.095132Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
mysql_container  | 2022-06-16T15:25:09.095175Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

My code if somebody needs visual help:

- Dockerfile

```
# node image version
FROM node:18

# Container directory
RUN mkdir -p /user/src/app

# Project path as a work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy package.json
COPY package.json ./

# Run command
RUN npm install -g typescript

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy source code
COPY . .

# Port
EXPOSE 3000

# CMD command
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

- docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  mysqldb:
      container_name: mysql_container
      command: --authentication_policy=mysql_native_password
      image: mysql
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_USER: johndoe
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
        MYSQL_DATABASE: Highschool_App

      ports:
        - "3306:3306"
      volumes:
        - ./database/Highschool_App.sql:/user/src/app/database
  app:
      container_name: node_container
      build: 
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      restart: always
      environment:
        MYSQL_USER: johndoe
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: Highschool_App
        MYSQL_HOST: mysql_container
        NODEPORT: 3000

      depends_on:
        - mysqldb
      volumes:
        - .:/user/src/app
      ports:
        - "3000:3000"
```

- My db connection script where the problem begins: 'db.js'

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');

require('dotenv').config();

const database = mysql.createConnection({
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    host:process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE
});

module.exports = database;
```

- And my entire env file

```
MYSQL_USER=johndoe
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
MYSQL_DATABASE=example
MYSQL_HOST=mysqldb

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_PORT=3306

NODEPORT=3000
```

I checked in another terminal for my container's ip, and it shows me that the ip where is trying to connect it's the same that is associated with my container:

```
sudo docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' mysql_container
```

My doubt is how can I establish a connection between both containers. PLease Help

Comment: `links:` is an obsolete option that activates a first-generation Docker networking mode.  You can safely delete it with no adverse consequences.  I've seen this help some similar problems; does deleting `links:` make a difference here?

Comment: To confirm, you're running `docker-compose up` and not some other command?  If you look at the extended logs, is the database fully started up by the time your application runs, or are there database initialization messages after the `ECONNREFUSED` error?

Comment: Looks like your mysql container never booted up successfully, Can you post logs of your mysql container?

Comment: To answer the three comments: I deleted the docker-compose's links's instruction and nothing appears to befixed(But many thanks for the deprecation info). IN secon place i use only the command 'sudo docker-compose up' to run my project

Comment: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.29-1debian10 started. | Switching to dedicated user 'mysql' | Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.29-1debian10 started. | Initializing database files | 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead. | /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.29) initializing of server in progress as process 42

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the

```
networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

in the docker-compose.yml and also the networks in your services.
I would also remove the links because it is obsolete.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I deleted the network and links but node notify me a connection refused message:"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED <ip>:3306 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1229:16)"... Mysql notify me that user root has been created with an empty password when i declare MYSQL_ROOT_PASS too.